# Dynamically loading posts with Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, load, infinite-loop

This [helpful idea from Andy Gaskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350246/loading-external-post-content-to-a-specific-div-jquery-wordpress) supports 50% of my next question:

I'd like to load posts dynamically with WordPress. Fetching them with Andy's function does work, but How do I bind the load to each and every one of the posts?

Can I insert PHP generated content (post permalink, for example) to the JS script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it:

```
$("#triggerDIV a").click(function(id){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent a element from executing
    var id = this.getAttribute('href'); // get the link
    $("#targetDIV").load(id); // load it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Jquery and Ajax in Wordpress Plugins](http://xplus3.net/2008/10/27/jquery-and-ajax-in-wordpress-plugins-public-pages/)?