# Get URL of selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just getting started with jQuery and I want to get the url of a selected element so I can do something with it.

To start with I'm just trying to get the url of a hovered link to show up in an alert.  Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
$(function() {

   $("table#content > tbody > tr > td > a[href*=delete]").hover(function(event){

   alert(this.value);

   });

});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
alert(this.href);
```

In your `hover` callback `this` represents the element which according to your selector I assume is an anchor tag. To get the URL this anchor points to you use the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a JS person myself, but I came up with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356861/dynamically-loading-posts-with-wordpress) to a similar problem; only not involving tables.

Hope it helps.